# obter os valores de uma lista genérica List<t>

Tags: c#, winforms, lista

Meu projeto *Winforms C#* possui um formulário com um componente `GridControl(gvDados)` e um botão *Processar* com um evento *Click()*. A validação se dá no evento *Click* do botão processar, através de um método responsável por retornar verdadeiro se existir um item selecionado e falso se não e posteriormente, que cada item seja armazenado em uma lista genérica.

```
List<string> itensSelecionados;
.
.
.
public bool RetornaSelecionado(bool Selecionado)
{
  List<string> itensSelecionados = new List<string>();

  foreach (int i in gvDados.GetSelectedRows())
  {
    DataRow row = gvDados.GetDataRow(i);       
    itensSelecionados.Add(row[0].ToString());
    //MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
  }
  if(linhas > 0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Selecionou " + itensSelecionados.Count()+ " Itens.");
    return Selecionado = true;
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Não selecionou");
    return Selecionado = false;
  }
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como posso obter também todos os itens salvos na lista `itensSelecionados` no evento *click()* do botão processar?
Eu pensei em fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
  foreach (var i in itensSelecionados)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(i);
  }
```

E estou obtendo o seguinte erro: `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Provavelmente está a ter esse erro porque a lista não está inicializada.

Comment: dentro da sua função  vc está redeclarando  a variavle List<string> itensSelecionados = new List<string>(); isso faz com  que ela esteja em  escopo local
Pata fazer ela ficar em  escopo global troque por itensSelecionados = new List<string>();

Comment: Era isso mesmo Marcos, funcionou após corrigir. Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> E estou obtendo o seguinte erro: System.NullReferenceException

Neste trecho de código `List<string> itensSelecionados = new List<string>();`, você está definindo um novo objeto chamado **itensSelecionados** dentro do escopo da função **RetornaSelecionado()**, exatamente igual ao objeto **itensSelecionados** definido no escopo do formulário.

Por causa disso, o objeto **this.itensSelecionados**, mesmo após executada a função **RetornaSelecionado()** continua sem ser inicializado.

Troque 
`List<string> itensSelecionados = new List<string>();`
 
por somente 
`itensSelecionados = new List<string>();`
para resolver

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo! muito obrigado Umberto!